# jQuery Animate on Background not working in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate

This works in Chrome, Safari and IE9.

```
$(".menu").animate({'background-position-y': '50%'}, 100);
```

But not in FireFox !

I'm a bit lost now, is there a simple fix for FF?

Comment: background-position-y is not part of the CSS specification. See: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-position-x/y` is not really part of any CSS spec, its IE specific CSS, added to IE5.5, and later implemented by Webkit.

The best solution is to use the `step` method, that will let you animate just about anything.

```
$('elem').animate({
  'border-spacing': -1000
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) {
    $(fx.elem).css("background-position", "0px "+now+"px");
  },
  duration: 5000
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q9aeh/1/